# Merging a DataFrame with some headers to a Master DataFrame with all headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have this master DataFrame `df` in which I have headers `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

Then, I have multiple DataFrames that I want to merge into the master DataFrame, but these ones don't have all the headers though they have headers that exist in the master one.

Example: `df1` has `['b', 'c']`, `df2` has `['a']` and so on.

Is there any way I can merge these DataFrames and that when I do, the data goes into the respective headers? Any help will be appreciated, I don't have a lot of experience with Pandas so if there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

EDIT: This is my goal. I want data that looks like this:

```
id|name|data
1|a|some
1|b|thing
1|c|here
2|a|another
2|c|stuff
3|a|and
3|b|that
```

To look like this

```
id|a|b|c
1|some|thing|here
2|another||stuff
3|and|that||
```

Comment: merged them on what rule, what's the goal?

Comment: I have edited my original question with my goal. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to pivot the vales  of the columns you can do that using pivot_table .

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   id name     data
0   1    a     some
1   1    b    thing
2   1    c     here
3   2    a  another
4   2    c    stuff
5   3    a      and
6   3    b     that

In [7]: pd.pivot_table(df , index = 'id' , columns = 'name' , values = 'data' , aggfunc = lambda x : ','.join(map(str, x ) ) ).reset_index()
Out[7]:
name  id        a      b      c
0      1     some  thing   here
1      2  another    NaN  stuff
2      3      and   that    NaN
```

`aggfunc = lambda x : ','.join(map(str, x )` this part you can change it's upto you how you want to handle if multiple values come for some (id, name) if thats not the case then you are okay .

Comment: I am getting the error `No numeric types to aggregate`. I guess I should've mentioned that the ID is alphanumeric. Is there any way around this?

Comment: ID being alphanumeric should not be a problem. can u post sample row of your data.

Comment: The print is the variable df. This is my code: a = pandas.pivot_table(df, index='Unique ID', columns='Info Name', values='Info')

Comment: please specify aggfunc as i have mentioned because of this you are getting this error

Comment: default aggfunc is mean and we don't have numeric data to compute mean ```pandas.pivot_table(df, index='Unique ID', columns='Info Name', values='Info' , aggfunc = lambda x : ','.join(map(str, x )```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212935/discussion-between-kunal-sawant-and-plasmy).